# Bash script - how to create time input field

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a simple script for a user to enter a specific time in the format of `--:--:--:--:----` (i.e. `10:46:02:17:2017`).  I would like to display the blank fields, have the cursor start at the left and move left to right and replace the `-` with a number as the user types.

How can this be best achieved in a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you headed in the right direction:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_var='';
printf "\r--:--:--:--:----\r";
while [ ${#my_var} -lt 12 ]; do
    read -s -n 1 this_char;
    if [ "$this_char" = " " ]; then
        this_char=0;
    fi;
    if [[ "$this_char" =~ [0-9] ]]; then
        my_var="$my_var$this_char";
    fi;
    hour="${my_var:0:2}"
    min="${my_var:2:2}"
    month="${my_var:4:2}"
    day="${my_var:6:2}"
    year="${my_var:8:4}"
    printf -v my_output "\r%-2s:%-2s:%-2s:%-2s:%-4s" $hour $min $month $day $year;
    my_output=${my_output// /-}
    printf "%s" "$my_output"
    output_length=${my_output%%-*}
    output_length=${#output_length}

    num_go_back=$(( 17 - ${output_length} ))
    for ((i=1; i<=$num_go_back; i++)); do
        printf "\b";
    done;
done;
echo

echo "hour: $hour"
echo "min: $min"
echo "month: $month"
echo "day: $day"
echo "year: $year"
```

Keeping in mind that this is probably not the best idea as it is not a normal interface on the command prompt. You'll want to edit the loop to make sure users are entering numbers and you'll want to check if fields are empty and replace them with a dash.

Comment: Seconded: "...this is probably not the best idea as it is not a normal interface on the command prompt."

Comment: Why `seq` (a nonstandard command not included with the shell), as opposed to C-style `for` loop support (guaranteed to be present in bash, which you need anyhow for `[[ $foo =~ $bar ]]`? I'd also strongly suggest `printf %s "$my_output"` instead of `echo -n $my_output` -- the behavior of `echo -n` is [implementation-defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). I'd also consider `printf -v my_output ...`, and `my_output=${my_output// /-}` to avoid subshell overhead -- and of course, your unquoted expansions should be quoted.

Comment: On a different note -- POSIX specifies all-caps names for variables with meaning for the OS and shell, and reserves lowercase names for application use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: This is nearly perfect for my use case.  There are two issues, however.  The cursor is one character ahead of where is should be.  When I enter the last 4 digits for a year, it gets converted to a 2 digit number on completion.   Can you please help solve this two problems?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : thanks for the feedback! I've implemented those fixes.

Comment: @OliverBradley : The script as posted works in a standalone file. Without more information I can't help you beyond that.

Comment: Thank you! As a further efficiency optimization, consider `printf -v my_output "\r%-2s:%-2s:%-2s:%-2s:%-4s" "$hour" "$min" "$month" "$day" "$year"; my_output=${my_output// /-}; my_output_prefix=${my_output%%-*}; output_length=${#my_output_prefix}` -- whereas ksh93 will optimize `out=$(printf ...)` to be run in-process for the existing shell, bash doesn't have those smarts, hence the `-v` argument; the above also provides a chance to skip `grep` and `wc`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I had looked in `man printf` and didn't see the `-v` flag. It works none-the-less, so I added that. Great feedback on optimizing this script!

Comment: See `help printf`, as opposed to `man printf` -- the man page only documents the external command (`/usr/bin/printf` or `/bin/printf`), whereas `help` documents the one built into the shell. The shell-builtin one has some other niceties, depending on your version of bash -- in both bash and ksh it can escape data to be `eval`-safe with `%q`, and with very new versions of bash (I think 4.3+?) it can do date/time formatting with `%()T`.